# Why using "document.getElementById" instead of using the ID to refer to elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So, I was coding in class when accidentally got to this point, when you set any ID in HTML5 a global variable is created at the same time, which can be used on the script aparently the same way we use getElementById().

for example:

```
<div id="identifier"></div>
```

can be accessed in the script like:

```
identifier.style.whatever
```

Can anyone explain me why I can't find any information about this? also, why isn't anyone using this when coding? is it bad to use this instead of getElementById?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331906/what-is-the-difference-between-getelementbyid-and-simply-using-an-elements-id-a