# How is my JS code accesing DOM elements without me explicity caching them first?

Tags: javascript, html, caching

Can someone help me understand why the textarea is being updated without caching it first

In my html I have a

```
<textarea id="inputData"></textarea>
```

and a reference to my js file which is:

```
(function(){
    "use strict"
    var analyzer = {
        text : [],
        init : function(){
            this.cacheDOM():
            this.render();
        },
        cacheDOM : function(){
           // Here is where I want to cache a portion of my DOM 
        },
        render : function(){
            inputData.value         = "my  data";
        }

    }// End analyzer

    analyzer.init();

})();
```

The result is the textarea being updated by the js file (render function), and I don't  know/understand why this is happening without me caching the DOM first...

PS: This happens with the "id"s property and not using "class"es.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't we just use element IDs as identifiers in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325221/why-dont-we-just-use-element-ids-as-identifiers-in-javascript)

Comment: that's a feature, not a bug. it can be handy, but you need to know about it (and it's ups and downs). on simple SPAs with well-named IDs (selUsers, tblHistoryGrid, inpPassword, etc), it can eliminate long-winded DOM methods or the need for a dom library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All html elements with ids are added to javascript to the `window` object as attributes. [See this for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

The reason is backward-compatibility I guess. Welcome to the world of front-end development,

Comment: Thanks a lot louy, and my next question was: do they become global... and the answer is right in the link you shared (Y).

Comment: You're welcome. In browsers, `window` is the global object. Anything under `window` is a global variable.