# How to alert input value

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

So I recently decided to try learning app development with Intel XDK, and as of now I know only little bit of HTML.

I'm trying to create a basic test app that allows the user to type a message in a text box, and then click the submit button which gives an alert that displays the inputted text.

This is what I have:

```
Message:
<br>
<input type="text" id="message" value="">
<br>
<button type="button" value="document.getElementByID(message)" onclick=alert(message)>Generate Text</button>
```

But when I run the app it displays `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value

Answer (score 4):

to get an element value use

```
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
alert( message );
```

Also, don't use inline JS. Rather assign an event handler

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {

    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    alert( message );

}, false);
```

**Here's a working example:**

```js
var message = document.getElementById("message");
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log( message.value );
});
```

```html
<br>
<input type="text" id="message" value="">
<br>
<button id="myButton" type="button">Generate Text</button>
```

Comment: Could you just use `alert(message.value)` ?

Comment: @guest271314 yes you can is you have your element stored into a `message` variable.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Believe  `id` is global

Comment: @guest271314 see my comment on your own answer.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Referenced your solution at own Answer.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I run the app it displays "[object HTMLInputElement]". How do
>   I fix this?

`message` at `html`, `javascript` references element having `id` `"message"` . You are calling `alert()` with `DOM` element `#message` as parameter. To correct this you can  pass `.value` property of `#message` : `message` to `alert(message.value)`.

Note, see [Why don't we just use element IDs as identifiers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325221/why-dont-we-just-use-element-ids-as-identifiers-in-javascript) .

You could alternatively attach a `click` event to `button` element and call `alert(document.getElementById("message"))` within `click` handler, as demonstrated by @RokoC.Buljan [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211220/2801559).

You are missing quotes around `alert()` at `onclick`, and `.value` at `message`

```html
Message:
<br>
<input type="text" id="message" value="">
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="alert(message.value)">Generate Text</button>
```

Comment: Relying on `message` being a HTMLDOMIDElement is démodée. Add a `message` variable in your logic and see your program fail.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Am not familiar with "démodée" ? What does term mean ? _"Add a message variable in your logic and see your program fail"_  Well, yes; there should not be two identifiers or variables with the same name

Answer (score 0):

You must use this function in alert and value just is a parameter that show as a button 
Try this instead:

```
Message: 
<br> 
<input type="text" id="message" value=""> 
<br> 
<button type="button" value="show" onclick=alert(document.getElementByID('message'))>Generate Text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementByID(message)` doesn't belong in the value attribute of your button, but should be inside your alert :

```html
Message:
<br>
<input type="text" id="message" value="">
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('message').value)">Generate Text</button>
```

#### Note

It's generally recommended to separate your HTML code from your JavaSCript code and use [**`Document.getElementById()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) instead of the HTML attribute `onclick` for adding click events.

So, that means it's best to rewrite the code here-above like this :

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
   alert(document.getElementById('message').value);
});
```

```html
Message:
<br>
<input type="text" id="message" value="">
<br>
<button type="button" id="button">Generate Text</button>
```

Comment: Sidenote: It's not good practice to rely on global ID variable referrers. Also it's not good practice to write inline JS.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan : I know. See the updated version of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to type this in value parameter of button:

```
document.getElementById(message).value
```

Thanks for fixing me guys.

Comment: what is `.text()` in JavaScript?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry, I added brackets accidentally.

Comment: you mean... `innerHTML` or `textContent` ? Even than it's an `input` and `value` should be used.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It returns the text of an element.

Comment: pretty sure it's .value for input fields

Comment: Yup, my mistake. It's value.

Comment: What's `getElementByID`? JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: @Quentin, it's calledd typo, I guess. Anyway, thanks for noticing.