# How to write a JavaScript "for" and "if" loop

Tags: javascript

So here I want to check the variable `lineOpt1_1` against 9 other variables- `varLine1_1`, `varLine1_2`, ......`varline1_9`

If it matches one of these, I want to hide a button "`Examples Button_1_1`" (cp.hide is used for adobe captivate):

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

    if (varLine1_[i] == lineOpt1_1) {

        cp.hide(Examples_Button_1_1);
    }
}
```

Could someone show me what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: `varLine1_[i]` is not what you think ... you may want `window['varLine1_' + i]` instead - if they are global vars ... if not, you need to rethink code you haven't posted

Comment: Try `eval("varLine1_"+i)`

Comment: You should be using arrays: http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html . There is basically never a reason to construct a variable name dynamically.

Comment: is 'Example_Buttons_1_1" a text?? or just class or id?

Comment: Examples_Button1_1 is just an id.

Comment: Timus2001 -  I think I see your point that it needs quotes.

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda - that did the trick.

Comment: @WIlliamStout If it's an id, you should use `document.getElementById("Example_Buttons_"+i)`, and [not `window[…]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25325221/1048572)!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to index an object, but not trying to access varLine1_**X** variables. As it's commented in the question, if these variables are global, there's no problem to get/index the global object with "varLine1_" + X:

```
window['varLine1_' + i]
```

If you want to do this using local variables, you'd need to use `eval` that parses/executes an code in the same scope where it has been called (this is also commented on the question).

```
eval('varLine1_' + i)
```

However it happens that these tricks make the code hard to work and understand. Try using objects / arrays (as commented, also):

```
var linesGroups = [
    [ 50 ]
];

// Confirm that the first element/prop "0" of linesGroups array
// is indexable
if (linesGroups[0])
    // Iterate each item of linesGroups[0]
    // if it's iteratable
    for (var item of linesGroups[0]) {
        if (item === lineOpt1_1) {
            cp.hide(Examples_Button_1_1);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hi Someone, unfortunately I don't understand, but could I ask another question?  This script works fine for my purposes- so I can see the variable is global.  Since the integer at the end of the button ID "Examples_Button_1_x" is always the same as the integer at the end of the variable 'lineOpt1_x' - is there a way to add a second looped integer "j"  to auto hide any button that ends wit the same integer as the "lineOpt1_" variable,so long as that "lineOpt1_" variable matches one of the varLine1_1 through varLine1_9 variables?

Comment: Something like:  `for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
 for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) 
{

    if (window['varLine1_' + i]== window['lineOpt1_'+ j]) {

        cp.hide("Examples_Button_1_”+j);
    }
}
}

Comment: @WTS14 Can you do a resume ?