# Javascript: Why get an element with getElementById(id) when it is still present in js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Lately i noticed that a reference to a html element with an id can be accessed by javascript simply with a variable named like that id ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/giroxuhuku/edit?html,js,console)).

why is this so? why do we have to even use `getElementById(id)` instead of simply writing `id`?

Comment: Duplicate of a couple of questions, e.g. [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/218196) and [Why don't we just use element IDs as identifiers in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25325221/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling: Good find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why is this so?

Because early browsers did that, and it's [now become standardized](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object).

> why do we have to even use `getElementById(id)` instead of simply writing id?

Technically, you don't. But beware that the global namespace is **really, really crowded**. There's a whole bunch of stuff thrown in there. Not just elements with IDs, but certain elements if they have `name`s, the browser context by name, etc., etc., which means there can be conflicts. For instance, if you had an element with `id="document"`, the automatic global won't be created. The other, conflicting globals can vary by browser. Also, `id` values that aren't valid JavaScript identifiers (like `id="foo-bar"`) are still perfectly valid `id` values, but the automatic global for it (`window["foo-bar"]`) is awkward to use.

Using `getElementById` specifically looks for an **element** with that **ID**<sup>1</sup> (not `name`, etc.). So it's more contained and reliable.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Ignoring bugs in obsolete versions of IE, which failed to constrain it correctly.*