# How were Chrome and other browsers able to initialize this JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, initialization

I'm working on a shopping cart that asks the user to check the box indicating they agree to the terms of service before they can "review order" and finally make the purchase.

I have to accomplish this with JavaScript by getting the element containing the "review order" and "continue shopping" buttons and changing the inner HTML to be what I need. I have to do it this way because the cart I am using does not give me full control over these elements in the cart source code.

Here is the code I originally came up with, which worked on Chrome, Edge, and other browsers, but not IE.

```js
var x = document.getElementById('CHECKOUT_LINKS');
x.innerHTML = '<div class="checkoutLinksBottom"><input id="tosBox" type="checkbox" name="tosBox">I agree to the <a href="http://example.com/terms-of-service/" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a><br><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);" class="continueButton">Continue Shopping</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="reviewOrderButton" class="continueButton" onclick="clicker();">Review Order</a></div>';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('#tosBox').addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
});


var checkbox = document.getElementById("tosBox");
checkbox.checked = true;
checkbox.checked = false;


function changeHandler() {
  if (!tosBox.checked)
    alert("You must agree to the Terms of Service");
}

function clicker() {
  if (!tosBox.checked)
    alert("You must agree to the Terms of Service");
  else { // Go to review order page
  }
}
```

As you can see the `CHECKOUT_LINKS` element's inner HTML is changed to what I need on the fly as the page loads. The primary point is to add the `id="tosBox"` element, then capture the click on `id="reviewOrderButton"` element and filter it though the simple JS functions `changeHandler()` and `clicker()`.

In IE developer tools, the console reports `'tosBox' is undefined` when I click on `id="reviewOrderButton"` element. This makes sense when looking at `var checkbox = document.getElementById("tosBox");` the variable created is called `checkbox`, but the variable I try to use later is called `tosBox`. I simply changed `checkbox` to `tosBox` and then everything worked on IE as well.

What's shocking to me is that the original code worked on Chrome and Edge. How did it work? Should I expect it to work and IE is faulting?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325221/why-dont-we-just-use-element-ids-as-identifiers-in-javascript. In short, DOM elements are automatically added to the global scope.

Comment: @Steve Wow, I'd never expect element id's to automatically become global variables. But from what I read, IE should have been doing it, but apparently wasn't.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty surprising to find out. All the more reason to use linters. I also try to use hyphens in my ids (like `tos-box`), so I don't accidentally access them.

Comment: @Steve Yeah, I may start something like that. I can't say I've heard of a linter, but after a search and learning what they are, I may use that too.