# console.log returns html element if variable not exists

Tags: javascript, html, console, global-variables

I'm totally confused about the behavior of `console.log()` when outputting a non-existing variable.

I was accidentally logging a non-existing variable `bon`. But the console didn't show `"undefined"` as expected, but `<div id="bon">`.

Searching where the variable was set (as I didn't set it and it had to be global, as it was popping up inside a function), I stripped all javascript, css and html untill there was nothing left at all:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head></head>
<body>
   <div id="bon">a</div>
   <script>
      console.log(bon);
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Testing in Firefox, Chrome, Explorer 11, Edge, Safari they all returned:

> < div id="bon">

Changing the script into

```
<script>
    function foo(){
        console.log(bon);
    }
    foo();
</script>
```

gave the same result.

Only this

```
   <script>
      console.log(bon);
      var bon="not bon";
      console.log(bon);
   </script>
```

gave the expected output:

> undefined
>   not bon

Am I missing something or does this mean the console just returns an element from the DOM with the same id if it can't find the variable itself?

**Edit**

As Chris G pointed out, the answer is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25325330/1685196). It turns out nowadays one can use id's to reference HTML elements in the global space without assigning them to a `var=`. But also: it is not recommended to do so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325221/why-dont-we-just-use-element-ids-as-identifiers-in-javascript

Comment: And as to why it works as expected in that one case, see the discussion about hoisting here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844

Comment: @Chris G _Poorly document_ is the right phrase. Just wasted 3 hours looking for this variable and Googling an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have a Div tag with the same ID and as "bon" has not been initiated anywhere in the Page. So "bon" automtically refers to the Div Tag.