# js get element from window['id'] vs document.getElementById('id')

Tags: javascript, dom, window, element, getelementbyid

What is better and what is the difference (performance, browser support...)?

I thought that DOM elements that have an id automatically create in a window object so you don't need to find them in DOM through getElementById. Am I right and what problems it could bring? I can't find any documentation on such a possibility of js window object.

Examples with window:

```
window['elementId'];
window.elementId;
```

The same result as getElementById and querySelector

Comment: Creating properties of the window object using element IDs was a very bad idea introduced in early IE (version 3?). It is supported by other browsers under the guise of legacy support, just don't do it. E.g. see [*Why JS function name conflicts with element ID?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id) and [*Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: Also [*Why don't we just use element IDs as identifiers in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325221/why-dont-we-just-use-element-ids-as-identifiers-in-javascript) Choose your dupe. ;-)