# Is it safe to replace document.getElementById("demoID").style.color = "blue"; with demoID.style.color = "blue";

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider this JavaScript code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementbyid2) (in Browser JavaScript):

```
  var x = document.getElementById("demoID");
  x.style.color = "blue";
```

1. Is it safe to replace it with this working code:

```
 demoID.style.color = "blue";
```

HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demoID">Click the button to change the color of this paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  // var x = document.getElementById("demoID");
  // x.style.color = "blue";
  demoID.style.color = "blue";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

2. What about performance (speed) comparing to [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)?

---

Edit:
I did a micro-benchmark `document.getElementById` is 3.7x faster:

HTML:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSigned" onchange="numberBase10changed()">Signed

    <div id="div2"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    let signed=false;
    let t0 = performance.now();
    for (let i=0; i<1000000; i++){
        // signed = document.getElementById("checkboxSigned").checked; // 88ms to 116ms
        signed = checkboxSigned.checked; // 369ms to 398ms
        g++;
    }
    div2.innerText = g+"interval = " + Math.trunc( performance.now()-t0 ) + "ms";
```

Result for `signed = document.getElementById("checkboxSigned").checked;`

```
88ms to 116ms
```

Result for `signed = checkboxSigned.checked;`

```
369ms to 398ms
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How could you call that "a working code"? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it works on my Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.

Comment: I can't try this at the moment, but it would be a surprise for me if this worked, I would guess that "demo" is undefined and it fails at that line.

Comment: @it'sBritneybitch The code doesn't fail at that line. New variables named by id attribute values are created to the global scope automatically, if the ids are unique within the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safe? .. Yes. Readable? .. No.

First, this works because all `id`'s are added to the window object. So `JS` will continue to traverse up the parent's scope till it hits the window.

Though I think this affects readability. It's unclear where `demo` is referenced or initialised. As you'll be looking for a `variable` declaration that you'll never find.

**From the HTML spec:**

> window[name]
>
> Returns the indicated element or collection of elements.
>
> As a general rule, relying on this will lead to brittle code. Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time, as new features are added to the Web platform, for example. Instead of this, use document.getElementById() or document.querySelector().

Comment: Well also, it's not really safe if this info is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325221/why-dont-we-just-use-element-ids-as-identifiers-in-javascript

Comment: True, I read "safe" in the security context

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What about performance (speed) comparing to document.getElementById?

Comment: Doubt there'll be any notable performance differences. I will consider this a macro performance issue, if that

Comment: Thanks, I did a benchmark  `document.getElementById` is 3x faster.

Comment: Nicee .. Are you able to share the results?

Comment: OK: See the new edit