# How to solve Uncaught ReferenceError in console?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I created a project with Django. I am using Chart.js in my index page. But when I look the console, there are several errors like:

```
(index):4078 Uncaught ReferenceError: doughnutChart is not defined
    at (index):4078
```

I do not know how to solve it. Here is my code:

**template.html**

```
<canvas id="doughnutChart"    ></canvas>
<script>
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(doughnutChart, {
           type: 'doughnut',
           data: {
               datasets: [{
                   data: ['{{ wait_senior_analyst|safe }}','{{ wait_lead|safe }}',
                       '{{ wait_manager|safe }}','{{ wait_regional_manager|safe }}',
                       '{{ wait_regional_director|safe }}','{{ wait_cfo|safe }}'],

                   backgroundColor: [   '#f6f349','#6def56',
                                       '#e90d73','#7f00d9',
                                       '#1df3f3','#ff7702']
               }],

               labels: [
               'Senior Analyst',
               'Lead',
               'Manager',
               'Regional Manager',
               'Regional Director',
               'CFO',
               ]
           },
           options: {
               responsive: true,
               legend : {
                   position: 'bottom',
                   labels: {
                   fontColor: {% if request.user.themeChoice == 'Light' %}"black"{% else %}"#d2fff2"{% endif %},
                   fontSize: 16
               }

               },



               layout: {

               }
           }
       });
</script>
```

Comment: What is `doughnutChart`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [the docs for chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html).

It looks like you are not passing a valid node, jQuery instance, 2d context, or string id of the canvas of where you want to draw the chart to `new Chart()`.

```
const ctx = document.querySelector('#doughnutChart');
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'doughnut',
   data: {...}
};
```

Alternatively, you can look at the [source code](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/4d99658155cdf3d504749b43cdc3ab71ab1d18d6/src/core/core.controller.js#L48).

Comment: Isn't `doughnutChart` [implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) a node?

Comment: Maybe in some cases, but that looks like a very unreliable way to work with the DOM. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25325330/5385381