Scroll-to-Top Button with Vanilla JS (Detecting the scroll position)
I have a problem and that is I have a back to top button but when I click on it it doesn't work
 <button class="scrollToTopBtn showBtn">☝️</button>


function scrollToTop() {
  // Scroll to top logic
  rootElement.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
scrollToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", scrollToTop);
document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
It's bugging this line and I expect it to work
scrollToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", scrollToTop);
And I expect the back to top button to work

What you might confuse here, is the use of an id. <button id="scrollToTopBtn">☝️</button>. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325221/why-dont-we-just-use-element-ids-as-identifiers-in-javascript .

 var scrollToTopBtn = document.querySelector(".scrollToTopBtn");
    var rootElement = document.documentElement;
    
    function handleScroll() {
      // Do something on scroll
      var scrollTotal = rootElement.scrollHeight - rootElement.clientHeight;
      if (rootElement.scrollTop / scrollTotal > 0.8) {
        // Show button
        scrollToTopBtn.classList.add("showBtn");
      } else {
        // Hide button
        scrollToTopBtn.classList.remove("showBtn");
      }
    }
    
    function scrollToTop() {
      // Scroll to top logic
      rootElement.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth" });
    
    }

scrollToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", scrollToTop);

It is better to post the complete code

Your code works for me. How is your HTML code? Is the button loaded on DOM when you attempt to set the addEventListener? Are you having any error in the console?

Also, I would suggest you omit handleScroll, as it's not doing anything useful in the problem you are asking about.

Maybe the problem is with my local area. Thank you all for responding. I will try it on a real host, maybe my problem will be solved.

You seem to need to use document.querySelector().  You cannot simply type a elements class name in Javascript.  You have to select the element.
Change this line:
scrollToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", scrollToTop);
To this:
document.querySelector(".scrollToTopBtn").addEventListener("click", scrollToTop);

I did this, unfortunately, I get the same error
